# Simultaneous wifi and 3G connection on mobile

Tags: iphone

I am developing a peripheral that uses WiFi and Embedded browser, the peripheral looks like an access point to iPhone (and android) but it is not connected to internet. When I connect my phone to this peripheral via Wifi, I loose internet connection on the phone using 3G.

Is there a way to avoid this? I have control over the software of the peripheral so I can change the IP addresses, gateways etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you going to connect your peripheral to the internet via iPhone's 3G network? If so, why don't you use iphone's [Personal hotspot feature](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2012/09/19/how-to-use-personal-hotspot-on-ios-6-and-the-iphone-5/)?

I believe you can't have both wifi & 3G connection without using Personal hotspot mode.

Comment: I expect these devices to be smarter than just, hey here is a wifi, let me connect, and now there is no connection and let me switch to 3G type behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can only simulate 3g on your device. In iOS 6 or higher open Settings->Developer->Network Link Conditioner-Status-Choose what you want.